# How to execute package.json script in Jenkins build

Tags: angular, jenkins, testing, jenkins-pipeline, package.json

I have declared some scripts in my package.json which i would like to execute in a jenkins job.
This is an example script:

```
"test-mutation": "stryker run",
```

And this is how i try to invoke it:

[image]

I've tried also just calling the script or just running "stryker run", but i receive that the command is not recognised -

```
npm-cli.js run test-mutation --scripts-prepend-node-path=auto

[SSH] executing...
bash: line 2: npm-cli.js: command not found
```

Comment: it means npm-cli.js is not missing. Just check whether `npm` is installed or not and also check whether the jenkins user has correct permission to run the `npm` commands.

Comment: @SouravAtta im quite new to jenkins, where do i check this?

Comment: in the server where jenkins is running oor if you are using slave then check the same in slave machine.

Answer (score 0):

Check if nmp-cli.js is installed on remote host (in your case it is 10.180.253.7).

Also check if it's folder is in PATH variable.